# Android ExpandableListView with single choice CheckBox at ChildView

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

Friends,

I am trying to write a ExpandableListView which use single choice checkboxes at ChildView.
And I can't understand how to set other CheckBoxes to "false" in OnChildClickListener() of ExpandableListView. Here is my code:

```
 ExpListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                if (cb.isChecked()) {           

                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    //Here somehow I must set all other checkboxes to false.
                            //Is it possible?
                }
                return false;
            }
   });
```

here is xml of ChildView :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textChild"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     />

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:focusable="false" 
      android:clickable="false" 
      android:layout_gravity="right" 
      android:visibility="visible"
/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can go recursively through all childs of ExpandableListView and find another checkboxes. or even better find first (if you don't know its id) parent view for selected section and get its checkboxes. Or even better - hold your checkboxes in array, change its checked state and call notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Comment: Can you explain me your second suggestion, please. This is what I want to do, but I'm new at Android and I can't understand how to seek other checkboxes in selected section

Comment: can you provide more code related to your ExpListView initialization and loading?

Comment: I've the same problem and I've tried something like this: http://pastebin.com/uk9b9qkx but it isn't working. Can someone look to my code?

Comment: @Gerrit Hoekstra please provide more code so that i can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to only be able to select one checkbox, you could store the checked checkbox in a variable `CheckBox checkedBox;`. When a `CheckBox` is clicked, you could do something along the lines of

```
@Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            CheckBox last = checkedBox  //Defined as a field in the adapter/fragment
            CheckBox current = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            last.setCheked(false);    //Unchecks previous, checks current
            current.setChecked(true); // and swaps the variable, making 
            checkedBox = current;     // the recently clicked `checkedBox`

            return false;
        }
```

Though, I'm not sure if this will work with Androids view recycle system, but it's worth a shot.

If you need multiple choices, you could expand the `checkedBox` into a `List<CheckBox>`, and iterate over it each time you need to uncheck boxes.

If you need to store some additional data (which you most likely need to), you could make a holder class, e.g.

```
class CheckBoxHolder{

    private CheckBox checkBox:
    private int id;

    public CheckBoxHolder(CheckBox cb, int id){
        this.checkBox = cb;
        this.id = id;
    }
    // Getter and/or setter, etc. 
}
```