# Expanable listview with singleChoice setSelectedChild not working

Tags: android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer

I have a singleChoice expandable listview, with choice indicating checkmark at left, as below

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/childElementSingleChoice"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

For this, the choice indicated check mark is not drawn when we choose, so i added `setChecked` in `onChildClick` .

NOw by reading from defaulPrreference, i want to populate the view being checked to the position obtained from preference.

Using `setSelectedChild(0,0,true)` is not working.

I already tried [the ExpandableListView ignore SetSelectedChild() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400024/the-expandablelistview-ignore-setselectedchild-method) and [Child selection in ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542892/child-selection-in-expandablelistview) but not working!

If it's due to over-riding the singleChoice check mark to be placed in left side instead of right side, then how can i achieve the same with this problem too solved?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293903/android-expandablelistview-with-single-choice-checkbox-at-childview

Comment: @DineshBalu This doesn't address my issue

Comment: Can you provide your listChoiceIndicatorSingle style also.  Do you have `state_checked=true` for the `drawableLeft`

Comment: I am using the android's api style attribute for style `?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle`, which as of i know is a reference to the drawable porvided with sdk. I don't have `state_checked=true` for `drawableLeft`, do i have to set it?

Comment: @DineshBalu, how to set/change `state_checked` for `drawableLeft`?

Comment: Check out creating xml StateDrawable